# ManyToManyField with through on an abstract model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, abstract, django-orm

Got an interesting one here.. I've shortened the models to make it easier to comprehend..

```
class Participant(Person):
    passport_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Passport Number'), db_column=u'PassportNumber')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Participant'

class Journey(BaseModel):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_participants', through=u'ParticipantJourney')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PlaneJourney(Journey):
    flight_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name=_('Flight Number'), db_column=u'FlightNumber')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'PlaneJourney'

class ParticipantJourney(BaseModel):
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant, verbose_name=_('Participant'), db_column=u'ParticipantId')

    journey_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='journey_content_type')
    journey_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    journey = generic.GenericForeignKey('journey_content_type', 'journey_object_id') # models.ForeignKey(Journey, verbose_name=_('Journey'), db_column=u'JourneyId')

    payment_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='payment_content_type')
    payment_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    payment = generic.GenericForeignKey('payment_content_type', 'payment_object_id') # models.ForeignKey(Payment, verbose_name=_('Payment'), db_column=u'PaymentId')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ParticipantJourney'
```

The ParticipantJourney model links a participant to a journey, now a journey is abstract because it can be made by any number of different methods of transport each of which will have their own respective fields. I think this setup is correct but I'm getting the following error message:

> Error: One or more models did not validate:
>   kandersteg.planejourney: 'participants' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model ParticipantJourney, which does not have foreign keys to Participant and PlaneJourney

I need to keep the manual definition of the link table so I can also link a payment to said journey so I don't really know where to go next with this, if anyone could shed some light I would be really greatful!

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

Django does not consider generic foreign keys as the required foreign keys in through model, and currently there is no way to define a ManyToMany relationship with through in an abstract base class.

However, there is a feature request in django ([ticket #11760](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11760)), that enables you to also use `%(class)s` in through field, e.g. by using `through='Pariticipant_%(class)s'` in `Journey` model, and then you must create the throught table manually for every child of `Journey`. But as I said, its just an open feature request yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define Journey as not abstract, but then you get the data split over multiple tables.

I found something interessing in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821384/1156004

Comment: Yeah that works but defeats the object of having it as abstract :(

Comment: Added the participant model, it's slimmed down greatly (well so are all the models) but you get the gist

Comment: I personally think it could be a bug in django because I had a look at the code where this is being generated and it doesn't seem to take into account GenericForeignKey fields when it was looking for the two ForeignKeys to constitute the ManyToMany

Comment: Would it be really that bad to make it not abstract?

Comment: No it wouldn't but I thought I'd see if anyone knew a way of getting it to work first before giving up..